# Why are Moq setup methods missing on my interface?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, moq

I have the following code, which passes interface into a function which expects a dictionary list of protocol handlers:

```
 var _protocolHandlers = new Dictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler>
                        {
                            {EmailAccountType.Pop3, new Mock<IEmailTransportHandler>().Object},
                            {EmailAccountType.IMAP, new Mock<IEmailTransportHandler>().Object}
                        };
```

Strange thing is though, that the following code doesn't give me the set-up methods on the mocked object:

```
_protocolHandlers[0].<where are set-up methods??>
```

It seems to follow the convention with normal interfaces passed into the constructor of a service, as these take interfaces, but they are injected using .Object().

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Setup methods are on the Mock 'container', not the actual mocked object which is what has been passed in.

If you create your mocks before, you'll be able to access the setup then pass in the object:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{        
    Dictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler> _protocolHandlers;
    Mock<IEmailTransportHandler> _mockEmailTransportHander = new Mock<IEmailTransportHandler>();        

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _protocolHandlers = new Dictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler>
                    {
                        {EmailAccountType.Pop3, _mockEmailTransportHander.Object},
                        {EmailAccountType.IMAP, _mockEmailTransportHander.Object} 
                    };
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1() 
    {
        _mockEmailTransportHander.Setup(m => m.Test()).Returns(false);
        // Rest of test
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2() 
    {
        _mockEmailTransportHander.Setup(m => m.Test()).Returns(true);
        // Rest of test
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. My _protocolHandlers will be instantiated in the NUnit TextFixture::Setup(). I need to invoke the set-ups within each Test (ie. setup the mock on the dictionary object), but from your example it looks like this is too late...?

Comment: @jaffa I have updated my answer for how it would work with nunit

Comment: Hi, this is great thanks! I use the original reference which is then used to add into the dictionary. Still can't work out why I can't access this off the dict. object though?!? I'm sure penny will drop;)

Comment: Because it's a dictionary, you have to access it with its key rather than index. e.g. `_protocolHandlers[EmailAccountType.Pop3]`

Comment: You can also use Mock.Get(object) to get the mock from the mock object.